# What's in Nintendo's "Dev Interface?"

Tags: nintendo

Not that long ago, Nintendo opened their [developer program](https://developer.nintendo.com) for access by anyone who registers a Nintendo Developer account, giving equal access to indie and commercial developers. Or, at least thats what the linked page says.

The [tools page](https://developer.nintendo.com) lists Unity and a HTML5 framework for game development, as well as the "Nintendo Dev Interface (NDI)." Since I am not really interested in developing using Unity (or HTML5, for that matter) I want to know what the NDI contains, at least in general terms.

(I don't doubt that at least some of that information is covered by an NDA, but I'd like to know as much as possible, since I can't register for a while)

I'm especially interested in what sort of compiler/languages are supported, what graphics APIs (and/or abstraction layers, like SDL) are allowed and how play testing works (some sort of compatability layer? Nintendo sanctioned emulation?).

Comment: Just checked; Google legitimately returns no useful information. My Google Fu is quite strong, too.

Comment: @Krythic Same :) I do believe that it must contain some commonly used libraries (`libjpeg`, `zlib`) as these are mentioned in the WiiU's licence iirc. Probably a C and/or C++ compiler (after all Unity's IL2CPP needs to convert to /something/ and lots of useful libraries are C) Probably also some OpenGL based stuff too. I'm also fairly sure its Windows only, which is kinda sad.

Comment: From the [description on the site](https://developer.nintendo.com/tools), it sounds like the NDI client is just a tool to help set up your development environment (downloading & installing relevant SDKs, environment variables/configurations, documentation...), not an engine or framework itself. The details of what SDKs etc installs would depend on which Nintendo platform you're targeting, and are very likely protected by NDA.

Comment: Personally I love Unity and think you might want to give that another look with my book (in my profile) but in the meantime I know you can also use MonoGame http://nintendoeverything.com/monogame-software-is-compatible-with-switch/

Comment: I know someone who's signed up for the program. He hasn't done jack with it, but he did sign up. I'll poke him and see if he'll let slip. (Old question, but still no answers)

Comment: And...just missed the edit window on my comment: nope, he has no idea either. He never installed it.

Comment: I don't really think it's possible to answer this question, since all of this stuff is under an NDA. I suggest signing up, the documentation states what tools / compilers and middleware are available, it's free afterall. The only downside is that you need to sign the NDA aswell.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it can not be (legally!) answered by anyone and is thus unanswerable. Nintendo is also _really_ strict about not telling anyone the details so I suspect no amount of editing will make this question answerable without being in a legal gray zone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*The following is my understanding of the NDI based on the sources linked below.*

The NDI, is a client software that will allow the user to connect to Nintendo servers to download SDKs, samples, drivers to connect to Nintendo development consoles, and Visual Studio extensions that provide built targets, debug interfaces and emulation environments.

*Note*: I am unaware whatever or not the NDI provides similar tools for a different IDE, other than Visual Studio. It also makes sense that if such tools exist, they would exist for Visual Studio given that Unity is part of the package. In addition, I have no idea of the extents of the debugging and emulation capabilities.

The NDI will allow you to manage different your packages depending on the target console of your projects and keep them up to date.

**Sources**:

- https://developer.nintendo.com/tools
- https://insights.dice.com/2017/01/16/develop-nintendo-switch/
- https://www.wiiubru.com/forum/index.php?threads/switch-development-units-sdev-and-edev.105/
- https://archive.is/Kpyar
- https://archive.is/dB4tR
- https://archive.is/1P4hS

**Disclaimers**:

- By making this post, I am not copying or distributing copyrighted content.
- I am currently - at the time of writing - not under a NDA with Nintendo, and I have not been part of their developer program.
- I am not and have not been - at the time of writing - an employee of Nintendo.
- The information in the linked sources did become available NOT at my fault.
- I receive no economic profit by making this post.
- My understanding of the NDI described above is the result of my own personal conjectures based on the information available on the linked sources.
- This post should NOT be considered a replacement for accessing Nintendo developer program or contacting Nintendo.

Comment: That sure are a lot of disclaimers to not be helt liable ;)
I don't really know but I guess this is still a very gray area and distributing these informations, even if they are available not because of you is not legal. Technically you are helping in distributing it and making it more popular/available. I won't downvote though.

Comment: @Nico I'm linking and... law about linking is not homogeneous around the world. Which is why I made sure to have enough grounds to claim fair use.

Answer (score 0):

This is impossible to answer. Since if you have access you are not allowed to tell these details. But what I would recommend you is to call Nintendo directly if you are really interested in developing for a Nintendo system. They might answer your questions.

Comment: This sounds more like a comment but it's close enough to an answer given all the other comments I've seen on the question. So, I'm not going to upvote but I don't think this answer deserves anything negative either.